# How to group records that are within 30days in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, recursive-query, date-arithmetic

I have records that spans more than 30 days.
I want to group such records that are within 30 days .
Example : The Order entered in 9/10 , All records within 30days belongs to this Order start date. Next which are beyond 30 days belongs to another group but we need to apply same Logic again.

```
ORD_ID  ORD_DT
O1      9/10/2022
O1      9/25/2022
O1      9/29/2022
O1      10/15/2022
O1      10/30/2022
O1      11/10/2022
O1      11/18/2022
O1      11/29/2022
O1      12/20/2022
```

My Expected Output is:

```
ORD_ID  ORD_START_DT    ORD_DT
O1      9/10/2022   9/10/2022
O1      9/10/2022   9/25/2022
O1      9/10/2022   9/29/2022
O1      10/15/2022  10/15/2022
O1      10/15/2022  10/30/2022
O1      10/15/2022  11/10/2022
O1      11/18/2022  11/18/2022
O1      11/18/2022  11/29/2022
O1      11/18/2022  12/20/2022
```

Here is the SQL for Input data

```
WITH  Order_Detail AS 
(
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-10') AS ORD_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-25') AS ORD_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-29')  AS ORD_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-10-15')  AS ORD_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-10-30')  AS ORD_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-11-10')  AS ORD_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-11-18') AS ORD_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-11-29') AS ORD_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-12-20') AS ORD_DT
)
SELECT ORD_ID, ORD_DT
FROM ORDER_DETAIL
```

Answer (score 1):

That’s a use case when a recursive query comes handy.

Assuming that your data is partitioned by order id and ordered by order date:

```
with recursive 
    data as (
        select o.*, 
            row_number() over(partition by ord_id order by ord_dt) rn
        from order_details o
    ),
    rcte as (
        select ord_id, ord_dt, rn, ord_dt as start_dt from data where rn = 1
        union all
        select d.ord_id, d.ord_dt, d.rn, 
            case when d.ord_dt > date_add(r.start_dt, interval 30 day) then d.ord_dt else r.start_dt end
        from rcte r
        inner join data d on d.ord_id = r.ord_id and d.rn = r.rn + 1
    )
select * from rcte order by ord_id, ord_dt
```

The first CTE enumerates the rows of each order; then, the recursive CTE starts iterating from the first record of each order, and applies the date logic on each row.